# -Dkarate.config.dir with full path on windows

Tags: karate

I want to test karate with dynamic variables for my clients.

I try to launch it with this command but it not work

Command :

```
java -jar "-Dkarate.config.dir=C:/Users/1234/Documents/Projects/Sace/IntegrationTests.City/bonneuil/configurations" karate.jar -e itg -T 5 -o C:/Users/1234/Documents/Projects/Sace/IntegrationTests.City/results/bonneuil/itg C:/Users/1234/Documents/Projects/Sace/IntegrationTests.City/bonneuil/features
```

The path in "karate.config.dir" is absolute and valid on windows, but when Karate start all "/" are stripped like you can see in the output below, I have test with blackslashes and double slash but It not work anymore :(

> C:Users1234DocumentsProjectsSaceIntegrationTests.Citonneuilconfigurationskarate-config-itg.js

Output :

```
11:13:53.338 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate version: 0.8.0.1
11:13:53.790 [main] INFO  c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - Karate version: 0.8.0.1
11:13:54.869 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration: could not find or read file: karate-config.js, prefix: CLASSPATH
11:13:54.878 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - skipping bootstrap configuration for env: itg - could not find or read file: C:Users1234DocumentsProjectsSaceIntegrationTests.Citonneuilconfigurationskarate-config-itg.js, prefix: FILE
11:13:54.897 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - <<<< feature 1 of 1 on thread pool-1-thread-1: infotrafic/sectors.feature
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: infotrafic.sectors
report: C:\Users\1234\Documents\Projects\Sace\IntegrationTests.City\results\bonneuil\itg\TEST-infotrafic.sectors.xml
scenarios:  1 | failed:  1 | skipped:  0 | time: 0,92
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas

Why karate remove / on the karate.config.dir path ?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I see it now. yes there may be a bug with karate on windows. I've been asking for folks to contribute to fix these, anyway - opened an issue here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/527 - meanwhile do you think you can use the approach in the docs to use a Java IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enclosing the path in quotes ?

```
java -jar -Dkarate.config.dir="C:/Users/1234/Documents/Projects/Sace/IntegrationTests.City/bonneuil/configurations"
```

Comment: Hi,

I try it but not work anymore, same result all slashes are removed from the path